# Why am I getting a generator object instead of an integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am parsing some XML from a website using `requests` and `bs4`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get("http://xml.skiddlecdn.co.uk/xml/affiliates/topsellers.xml")

if r.status_code == 200:
    data = bs(r.text, 'xml')
    raw_dates = data.find_all('date')
    dates = [date.string for date in raw_dates]
    for date in sorted(dates):
        print("{}. {}".format(i for i in range(1, len(dates))), date))
else:
    r.raise_for_status()
```

My expected result:

```
1. 2017-01-17
2. 2017-01-20
3. 2017-01-20
# etc...
```

My actual result:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x06022B70>. 2017-01-17
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x06022B70>. 2017-01-20
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x06022B70>. 2017-01-20
# etc...
```

Why?

Comment: Your first argument to the `format` function is `i for i in range(1, len(dates))`, which is in fact a generator. You could put a `list()` around it, but that still wouldn't give you the expected result. You want a print for every date, so the `print` statement definitely needs to be inside the `for` loop (like in coldspeed's answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It prints a generator, because you pass it a generator. I'm assuming you just want to display the date with an index value. Why not use `enumerate` instead?

```
for i, date in enumerate(sorted(dates), 1):
    print("{}. {}".format(i, date))
```

Comment: How does his code even work? There are 4 opening and 5 closing brackets in the `print` line. Pretty sure this would throw a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @jsmolka I took a leap of faith and assumed OP tried dumbing this down to produce a [mcve] but failed. Their actual code *seems* to work, and this would be the culprit in that case. :)

Comment: @coldspeed Your leap of faith was misplaced I'm afraid - I didn't catch that (and neither did sublime-anaconda). Other than that, clear and pythonic answer -marked as accepted - thanks.

Comment: @DDiran Haha, no worries, I always try to give people the benefit of the doubt where possible.